# WebView.Eval not call javascript function inside my HTML - Xamarin Forms

Tags: javascript, html, xamarin, webview, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to use the Eval function of the WebView control to run a javascript function into my WebView. The WebView loaded correctly my HTML with the Javascript function, but when I use WebView.Eval(javascript_function), nothing happens and the function is not called.
Here my CS code:

```
var _Script = string.Format("enableBeacon(\"{0}\") ", id);
        _WebViewMap.Eval(_Script);
```

Here my Xaml:

```
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">
<WebView x:Name="WebViewMap" WidthRequest="1000" HeightRequest="1000" Source="{Binding HtmlSource.HtmlUrlSource}"/> 
</StackLayout>
```

Here my Javascript function:

```
function enableBeacon(id)
{
 var myBeacon = document.getElementById(id);
 myBeacon.style.display = "";
alert("I am an alert box!");
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: That all looks correct. However not sure how picky the `WebView.Eval()` method is about white space. Your sample code shows an extra space after the close parenthesis. You have `"enableBeacon(\"{0}\") "` so perhaps try `"enableBeacon(\"{0}\")"` note not extra space after the closing parenthesis.

Comment: I tried to remove the blank space from my function "enableBeacon" but still the WebView not call the Javascript inside..

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
webView.Navigated += (o, s) => {
 webView.Eval("alert('text')");
 };
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Answer (score 0):

I believe Kamil was correct.

The webpage must finish loading before you can call Javascript using WebView.Eval.

Here is my code to demonstrate:

```
public partial class WebViewPage : ContentPage
{
    public WebViewPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        BindingContext = new WebViewPageViewModel();
        this.Title = App.CurrentProfileHeader;

        MyWebView.Navigated += MyWebView_Navigated;

    }

    private void MyWebView_Navigated(object sender, WebNavigatedEventArgs e)
    {
        string token = "Hello from the C# World! 2";
        MyWebView.Eval("displayToken('" + token + "')");
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        string token = "Hello from the C# World!";
        MyWebView.Eval("displayToken('" + token + "')");

    }
}


<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body onload="myFunction()">
    <p>Hello Cruel World!</p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function displayToken(token)
        {
            alert(token);
        }
        function myFunction() {
            alert("Page has loaded");
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Using this code, you should see that "onappearing" fires before the html page onload event. However the navigated event fires after the html page has fully loaded.